# Hamachi Installation Fails

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux, software-installation, vpn

I'm trying to install hamachi on my Raspberry Pi.  I had it installed previously but had to wipe the card after a failed update so here I am again.  Every time I run the install script it fails.  See below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
root@raspbmc:/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.101-armel# ./install.sh
Removing previous version ..
Stopping LogMeIn Hamachi engine ..
Stopping LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachihamachid: no process found
. ok 
Removing LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
Removing LogMeIn Hamachi symlink ..
Removing files from /opt/logmein-hamachi ..
LogMeIn Hamachi is removed.
Copying files into /opt/logmein-hamachi ..
Creating LogMeIn Hamachi symlink ..
Installing LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachi/sbin/start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin/hamachid (No such file or directory) failed! 
LogMeIn Hamachi is installed. See README for what to do next.
```

OS: RASPBMC

Comment: I'm guessing raspbmc from the first line.  But it would also be good to know where you got hamachi from (not a deb from logmein, it seems) and what is the result of `ls /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin`

Comment: I'm using RASPBMC as my OS, I got Hamachi from a link in the Raspberry Pi Forums, the current version on their site doesn't work with Raspberry Pi.  This is the last version that did work, it's the same one that I used to install it last time when it worked...and the output of the above command is

root@raspbmc:~# ls /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin
dnsdown  dnsup  hamachid

So yes the file is there, why it's saying it's not baffles me.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /lib/ld-linux.so.3`

Ref: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7684048.html